# Sleep for a while onclick of a button

Tags: javascript, jquery

Currently i have the following

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#abc').click(function () {

        setTimeout(function () {
            //do stuff
        }, 2000);

    });
});
```

Is there a better way to do it, perhaps something like this

```
$('#abc').click(function () {
    // sleep/delay or whatever

    //do stuff
});
```

Comment: Generally, no. Aside from timers, you're rather limited to blocking the thread with an indefinite loop, which halts all other code and freezes the UI. Very rarely could this be considered a good thing.

Comment: No, in JS there's no `sleep()` like in PHP. JS works in the main thread, so blocking execution would freeze the UI.

Comment: Try using the `delay(2000)` in `JQuery` .

Comment: Embrace asynchronicity - not only in JavaScript where you don't have much of a choice, but in the design of any system.

Comment: @KitePlayer `.delay()` can work, but only when also using [`.queue()`](http://api.jquery.com/queue/). Though, it's also [a wrapper for `setTimeout()`](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/queue/delay.js).

Comment: No there is no such "Run,Delay,Run" functionality in javascript. setTimeout is your only option. There is delay though but you use that for animation.

Comment: @Jonathan ok. I am not aware of that `queue()`.Thanks for your info

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no better way. In order to sleep synchronously you need to use a spinlock which will use all the browser's resources and spike the CPU for 2 seconds (the duration of the "sleep").

Stick with the asynchronous version.

Answer (score -1):

```
$('#abc').click(function () {
    $(this).delay(seconds);

    //do stuff
});
Try this
I dunno wheather it works
```

Comment: hmmm... i dont think there is a sleep function in js or jquery